# iOS InAppBrowser not showing HTML select properly

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser

I'm building an app using Ionic 2.

Not sure if this is related to Ionic 2 or Cordova, but maybe you can guide me in the right direction.

I'm using an InAppBrowser component to show an HTML page which have an HTML select component, and when the options are shown in iOS the "done" button is not shown, so a selection can't be made.

This is happening in the emulator and in a real device. It works fine in android.

I'm attaching an image just in case, but I did reproduce this in other websites too.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuJ9z.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
 window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);          
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because iOS needs the extra InAppBrowser Option: `presentationstyle: "formsheet"`, to render those buttons:

```
this.inAppBrowser.create(
    url,
    target,
    {
        presentationstyle: "formsheet", // iOS only option
    },
);
```

As described in this answer, which answers basically the same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149158/10005883