# Ionic 4 missing buttons on select dropdown element in InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, ionic4

Opening a page with the `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and opening a `dropdown/select` list, I get the list, but without any confirm or cancel buttons displayed. I do get these outside of the inAppBrowser, in my normal app.

This answer does not solve my question, because the element is inside the inAppBrowser, I think:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41203014/10005883

Now I can't close the select / dropdown element, unless I "click" something on the page containing this element.

Is there any way to add buttons to the select / dropdown element in the **inAppBrowser**? I want the user to be able to close this select element from the select element.

Using:

```
"cordova-ios": "~4.5.4"
"cordova-plugin-ionic": "^4.1.3"
"@ionic-native/core": "^4.6.0"
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^2.0.2"
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get now, I want buttons at the top of the grey block:

[image: select dropdown not showing any cancel or confirmation buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [the documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#cordovainappbrowseropen) again, I started trying random options.
The solution is to use "formsheet" as presentationstyle, in the options:

```
this.inAppBrowser.create(
    url,
    target,
    {
        presentationstyle: "formsheet", // iOS only option
    },
);
```

See screenshot, for the effect:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJL4F.jpg)

Comment: Is this fix still valid? I am getting it still.